# Android set image from URI on ImageView

Tags: android

**UPDATED with more code**

I am trying to grab a picture that was just taken and set it to an `ImageView` programmatically.

The picture button is pressed,

```
picture_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        takePhoto(mTextureView);
    }
});
```

it runs the takePhoto method:

```
public void takePhoto(View view) {
    try {
        mImageFile = createImageFile();
        final ImageView latest_picture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.latest_picture);
        final RelativeLayout latest_picture_container = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.latest_picture_container);
        final String mImageFileLocationNew = mImageFileLocation.replaceFirst("^/", "");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + mImageFile, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(mImageFile);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+uri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        latest_picture.setImageURI(uri);
        latest_picture_container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    lockFocus();
    captureStillImage();
}
```

which runs `createImageFile()` and `captureStillImage()`

```
private void captureStillImage() {
    try {
        CaptureRequest.Builder captureStillBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
        captureStillBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());
        int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        captureStillBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
        CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
                super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                unLockFocus();
            }
        };
        mCameraCaptureSession.capture(captureStillBuilder.build(), captureCallback, null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(new Date());
    String subFolder = "";
    if(pref_session_unique_gallery.equals("yes")){
        if(event_name != null){
            subFolder = event_name;
        } else {
            subFolder = timestamp;
        }
    } else {
        subFolder = "_GEN";
    }
    if(event_name == null){
        event_name = "";
    } else {
        event_name = event_name + "_";
    }
    String imageFileName = "CPB_"+event_name+timestamp+"_";
    File storageDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "CPB" + File.separator + subFolder);
    storageDirectory.mkdir();
    File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDirectory);
    mImageFileLocation = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

and image is saved here:

```
private static class ImageSaver implements Runnable {
    private final Image mImage;
    private ImageSaver(Image image) {
        mImage = image;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];
        byteBuffer.get(bytes);

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;

        try {
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mImageFile);
            fileOutputStream.write(bytes);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            mImage.close();
            if(fileOutputStream != null){
                try {
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
```

I am getting the correct path to the image after `createImageFile()` and toasting it to show what it is every time. But not even the `setVisibility` on `latest_picture_container` is working...  If I comment out the `InputStream`, `Bitmap` and `setImageBitmap`, then the `latest_picture_container` shows up as normal.  Not sure why this is wrong.

For some reason, the URI is coming back with three slashes after file,

```
file:///storage/0/...
```

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the correct path to the image? Have you tried printing out the path?

Comment: @4k3R I just found out the path is placing in an extra `/` after `file://` so I'm trying to figure out where that's coming from and how to get rid of it

Comment: @4k3R, I've added the create image method if that helps.

Comment: Where did you store your image?

Comment: @tinysunlight, it's stored at the end of the last method I've just added

Comment: I haven't see how you store the image in file.Where is the image? file:///storage/0/... is normal uri format.

Comment: @tinysunlight, just included the `ImageSaver` class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `AssetManager#open()` method only works for your app's assets; i.e., the files in your project's `/assets` folder. Since you're trying to open an external file, you should instead use a `FileInputStream` on a `File` object created from the path. Additionally, the `takePhoto()` method is setting the image on the `ImageView` before anything has been written to the file, which will result in an empty `ImageView`.

Since your app is using the camera directly, we can decode the image from the same byte array being written to the image file, and save ourselves an unnecessary storage read. Furthermore, in the example your code follows, the file write is happening on a separate thread, so we might as well take advantage of that in performing the image decode, as it will minimize the impact on the UI thread.

First we'll create an interface through which `ImageSaver` can pass the image back to the `Activity` to display in the `ImageView`.

```
public interface OnImageDecodedListener {
    public void onImageDecoded(Bitmap b);
}
```

Then we'll need to alter the `ImageSaver` class a bit to take an `Activity` parameter in the constructor. I've also added a `File` parameter, so the `Activity`'s corresponding field need not be `static`.

```
private static class ImageSaver implements Runnable {
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final Image mImage;
    private final File mImageFile;

    public ImageSaver(Activity activity, Image image, File imageFile) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mImage = image;
        mImageFile = imageFile;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];
        byteBuffer.get(bytes);

        final Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ((OnImageDecodedListener) mActivity).onImageDecoded(b);
                }
            }
        );

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        ...
    }
}
```

As soon as we get the image data in the byte array, we decode it and pass it back to the `Activity`, so it doesn't have to wait on the file write, which can proceed quietly in the background. We need to invoke the interface method on the UI thread, since we're "touching" `View`s there.

The `Activity` will need to implement the interface, and we can move the `View`-related stuff from `takePhoto()` to the `onImageDecoded()` method.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
    implements ImageSaver.OnImageDecodedListener {
    ...

    @Override
    public void onImageDecoded(Bitmap b) {
        final ImageView latest_picture =
            (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.latest_picture);
        final RelativeLayout latest_picture_container =
            (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.latest_picture_container);

        latest_picture.setImageBitmap(b);
        latest_picture_container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void takePhoto(View view) {
        try {
            mImageFile = createImageFile();
            captureStillImage();
            lockFocus();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Finally, we need to actually execute the `ImageSaver` in the `ImageReader`'s `onImageAvailable()` method. Again following the example, it would be something like this.

```
private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener = 
    new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
        mBackgroundHandler.post(new ImageSaver(MainActivity.this,
                                               reader.acquireNextImage(),
                                               mImageFile)
        );
    }
};
```

Comment: Absolutely amazing Mike,  Thank you for all of your hard work and help

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is use the Picasso library

Add the dependency to build.gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

***Since you are getting the file path, set the path to a File object, and then let Picasso grab the image from the phone, and set it to the required ImageView***

```
File fileLocation = new File(uri) //file path, which can be String, or Uri

Picasso.with(this).load(fileLocation).into(imageView);
```

I do recommend using Picasso for any kind of Image activity on your app, whether it's online or offline. Picasso is made by Square, and is the best when it comes to image loading, caching...

Answer (score 1):

try this simple code

```
ImageView imgView = view.findViewById(R.id.lw_foto);

imgView.setImageURI(mListaContactos.get(i).foto);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getEDirectory(String folderName,Activity activity) {
    if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equalsIgnoreCase(Environment.getExternalStorageState())){
        LogUtils.e( activity.getExternalFilesDir(folderName).getAbsolutePath());
        return activity.getExternalFilesDir(folderName).getAbsolutePath();
    }else{
        return activity.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() +File.separator+folderName;
    }
}    
public static Uri getImageUri(String shortname,Activity activity) {

    if (shortname == null) {
        shortname = "www.jpg";
    }
    String path = DataStore.getEDirectory("pure",activity);
    File files = new File(path);
    files.mkdirs();

    File file = new File(path, shortname);
    return Uri.fromFile(file);

}
    public static Uri attemptStartCamera(Activity ctx){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        String latestfilename = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
        Uri imageUri = getImageUri(latestfilename,ctx);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
        ctx.startActivityForResult(intent, MsgCodes.PICK_CAMERA);
        return imageUri;
    }
```

In Activity:

```
mUri = attemptStartCamera(Activity.this);
```

In this way,you get the Uri.

You can load your image In the onActivityResult:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==MsgCodes.PICK_CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        mImageView.setImageUri(mUri);
    }
}
```